# New VGA display modes get lost when I turn off/restart computer

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, monitor

I recently added various 16:9 display modes to my second monitor (connected on the VGA connector) following a youtube tutorial. It worked fine. But after restarting the computer the display options are back to the default 4:3 resolution, and the added ones (16:9) are not there any more.
Do you have to "save" settings manually? that gets tediuos.

**--UPDATE--**
The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (64 bit)
Graphics: GeForce GT 620/PCIe/SSE2 / GeForce GT 620/PCIe/SSE2
Gnome vers 3.36.8

The procedure I found in youtube and followed in the terminal is (now doing for 16:10 res):

```
cvt 1680 1050

xrandr --newmode "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 1680x1050_60.00
```

*after that I must change resolution in the settings>monitors panel.* It works. But after restart I must do all again.

**-- Update --**
This is the latest configuration that works for my DELL monitor:

```
cvt 1366 768

xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 1368x768_60.00
```

This works well: after adding those lines in the terminal Ubuntu "recovers" the last monitors configuration used before restart and hence the resolution and positions of both monitors to each other (one on top of the other). *That means I don't need to change anything again in the settings>monitors panel.* But I would like to know where this change can be made permanent, what files must I edit, and not need to add a mode every new restart.

Comment: You have not given any real information. Useful information includes which version of Ubuntu? Exactly how have you added the modes? Have you read and tried: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr#Permanently_adding_undetected_resolutions

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: @waltinator just updated the post..tnx.

Comment: @codlord the linked info looks good... but I don't have any experience in ubuntiu... I don't know where these files are: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/" "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitor.conf". 
A step by step description would help me. Tnkx.